# Where and how can I copy flash-animated html content inside a Lotus Notes database in order to invoke from a document or page?

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus

I know Domino as a web server. In the data folder there´s an HTML folder which is normally the root of web content. But I want to put files and folders with all the flash stuff inside a Notes database (nsf).

I know I can do this via import through Package Explorer in the Notes Designer client. But where should I copy it into? Into *webcontent* folder?

I also know documents and pages can act as *.html* files. But there are also javascripts, *.swf*, *.mp3* and other files.

How can I then invoke the starting point file like *index.html*?

I appreciate any helpful answer .. :-)

Answer (score 3):

> I know I can do this via import through Package Explorer in the Notes
>   Designer client. But where should I copy it into? Into webcontent
>   folder?

I would not recommend to put it on Domino server file system, it's very dirty way.

1. One document with one attachment/video. That would give you overview of all files you have in database plus possibility to add/delete them (require development skills little bit).
2. You can also upload your resources as Files as a design element, however that would require you design access each time you want to change them.

[image]

- About invoking. Have a look here: [Domino URL Commands](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ABOUT_DOMINO_URL_COMMANDS_4332.html)
- Also check this link: [URL commands for opening attachments, image files, and OLE objects](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ABOUT_URL_COMMANDS_FOR_OPENING_IMAGE_FILES_ATTACHMENTS_AND_OLE_OBJECTS.html)

Comment: Very good answer. But using image resources for about everything comes from times when there were no file resources. If you change your screenshot to show adding file resources, then your answer would be even better

Answer (score 1):

For everything that is not plain html you can use file- resources. Linking them is as simple as write an url that looks like this: 
`hxxp://yourserver.com/yournsf.nsf/JSLibrary.js?OpenFileResource`

You can find all possible URL- commands in your designer help or in [this URL cheat sheet](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-Domino_URL_cheat_sheet/)